# Como recibir y retrasmitir buffer en C++

Tags: c++

Buenos dias estoy tratando de crear un proxy para propositos de aprender, pero tengo una falla cuando quiero re-trasmitir el buffer 
del servidor a el cliente, aca mi funcion:

```
send(Socket_Server,Reques,strlen(Request),0);
int receive = 0;
while(receive = recv(Socket_Server,buff,BUFFER_SIZE,0) > 0){
    send(Socket_Server,buff,BUFFER_SIZE,0);
}
```

Como puedo crear la funcion adecuada que pueda manejar Chunk-Encoding y no perder informacion en la re-trasmision.

Answer (score 1):

```
receive = recv(Socket_Server,buff,BUFFER_SIZE,0)
```

Se supone que ahí estás recibiendo `receive` bytes de datos y tu lo que pretendes es reenviar únicamente esos datos... no todo el buffer, ¿cierto?

Entonces `send` debería quedar así:

```
send(Socket_Server,buff,receive,0);
```

Lo que hace tu código es transmitir el buffer al completo, el cual contendrá, como norma general, basura al final del mismo.

El código completo:

```
send(Socket_Server,Reques,strlen(Request),0);
int receive = 0;
while(receive = recv(Socket_Server,buff,BUFFER_SIZE,0) > 0){
    send(Socket_Server,buff,receive,0);
}
```